# Difference b/w Settings.Global ,Settings.System and Settings.Secure in android

Tags: android

There are 3 inner classes in `android.provider.Settings`:

1. Global
2. System
3. Secure

Each class has a different type of Preference. Can someone explain the role/scope of each of these classes?

Answer (score 5):

From the Android developer docs:

- [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) : System settings, containing miscellaneous system preferences. This table holds simple name/value pairs. There are convenience functions for accessing individual settings entries.
- [Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) : Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write. These are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values, not modified directly by applications.
- [Settings.Global](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) : Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply identically to all defined users. Applications can read these but are not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values

Comment: Just copy/paste

Answer (score 4):

[`Settings.Global`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global) was introduced in API 17, and now contains some values that were previously stored in `Settings.System`.

e.g. prior to API 17, the Device Name was stored in `Settings.System`, and now it is stored in `Settings.Global`.

(see related post for info on that: [Android : Get “device name” on android tv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44460486/383414))

Answer (score 1):

**Settings.Secure** is same like **Settings.Global**
Both are can be modified only by Settings apps or SystemUI app
and other apps can read them
Only difference is that Global will be applied to all users

On the other hand **Settings.System** can be modified by apps that uses dynamic preferences or other system apps