# Android : Get "device name" on android tv

Tags: android, android-tv, device-name

I know this question is something that is often asked but no matter what I tried I couldn't find the answer.

I use an AVD android TV (API 24) and want to access this :

[image]

How can I access this name in my app ? Even with adb I never found it...

Comment: is that a name of your AVD?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes it's a name I defined myself in settings-->about-->device name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33566247/940834 Try using the bluetooth provider. Use try, catch or check for nulls though, incase its not suported

Comment: @Doomsknight I already tried but it return null. My adb doesn't seems to have bluetooth. But I can set the "device name", so I should be able to access it

Comment: You can probably access it on a real device, that has bluetooth, using that method. I suggest testing on a real device. Where as an AVD you will have issues.

Comment: @Doomsknight I didn't test it, I will be able to in 1 or 2 hour, but I know that the android TV I'm testing with doesn't have bluetooth :/ is there a better solution ?

Comment: There are various suggestions on stackoverflow, but none that seem 100% reliable.

Comment: @Doomsknight Can propose me some ? I already searched (if not I wouldn't have asked my queston) but I found nothing that worked. Even the guys that proposed ADB were wrong (in android TV at least)

Comment: Search for getting android device name, rather than specifically TV.
 As it should be the same solution. [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281/get-android-device-name) [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704597/how-do-you-get-the-user-defined-device-name-in-android)

Comment: @Doomsknight I already tried all oh them, to me they all return null expet for Build.Manufacturer + " " + Build.MODEL that is no really a name :/ To tell you I even tried a Linux command to search "MyAwesomeCustomeName" in adb but couldn't find it ><

Comment: Bluetooth name is not the same as Device Name (at least not on some devices). The Pixel on Android P allows 2 different names for those 2 fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is worked for my AVD (API level 24).

```
String deviceName = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name");
```

Instead of the string "device_name", you can also use the constant [`Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#DEVICE_NAME).

---

This property was moved into `Settings.Global` in API 17.

Before API 17, the following code should work:

```
String deviceName = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name");
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY GOD !!!!!!!!!!! It worked just fine on AVD for me too ! I can't test on a real TV till monday but you can be sure I will post if it works or not ! Thanks man, really thank you !